# Adjacent SKPhysicsBody not working properly

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit, game-physics

I am having a problem when trying to put two blocks that have physics bodies on top of one another.

http://s1173.photobucket.com/user/Kyle_Decot/media/example_zps02f027fe.mp4.html

As you can see in the video I am able to place my block on top of the stacked blocks even though they are placed right on top of one another.

Both the player block and the other blocks inherit from a base `Block` class which looks like this

```
#import "Block.h"

@implementation Block

+ (void)loadSharedAssets {

}

- (id)initWithColor:(UIColor *)color size:(CGSize)size {

    self = [super initWithColor:color size:size];

    if (self) {

        self.texture = [SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"tile"];

        self.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize: self.size];
        self.physicsBody.usesPreciseCollisionDetection = YES;
        self.physicsBody.dynamic = NO;


    }

    return self;
}

@end
```

**Update**

I've added a picture to make the problem a little more clear. Essentially the problem is that even though the blue blocks are right above one another, I am still able to jump up (w/ the red block) and sit on the edge of the bottom blue block (which shouldn't be possible). It seems something is off w/ the physics bodies or something.

[image]

You can see that the red block is *slightly* higher than the adjacent blue block for some reason and "sits" on the edge of the bottom blue block. when I jump up against it.

Comment: I don't understand your question. Do you want the red block to keep aligned on top of the blue moving blocks? but as I could see in the video, the red one ended up next to the blue blocks instead of on top of them?

Comment: The two blue blocks are placed directly on top of one another so I shouldn't be able to jump up w/ the red block and rest on top of the lower blue block (but I'm able to)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT: replaced original suggestion with answer**

Scrolling to section **4.5 Edge Shapes** of the [box2d documentation](http://www.box2d.org/manual.html#_Toc258082970) and you will find the cause of this (SpriteKit uses Box2D under the hood for it's physics implementation)

> In many cases a game environment is constructed by connect several edge shapes end-to-end. This can give rise to an unexpected artifact when a polygon slides along the chain of edges. In the figure below we see a box colliding with an internal vertex. These ghost collisions are caused when the polygon collides with an internal vertex generating an internal collision normal.

The two edges here (edge1 and edge2) are the left hand side edges of the two blue boxes in your game (so picture it rotated 90 digs counter-clockwise)

[image]

Box2D introduced *ChainShapes* to get around this issue (which you can find referenced in section **5.6 Edge Shapes**.

The idea is to replace groups of square physics bodies with a chain of these vertices whenever generating more than one box at the same time.

I believe you can access these within SpriteKit by using [bodyWithEdgeChainFromPath](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKPhysicsBody_Ref/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/SKPhysicsBody/bodyWithEdgeChainFromRect:) and passing in a Core Graphics path consisting of the corner points of the boxes you want to combine to form the collision chain

Comment: I have a method called `jump` and in there I'm setting the velocity `self.physicsBody.velocity = CGVectorMake(30, 350);`. Is this not a safe thing to do?

Comment: Try applying an impulse to the sprite in question instead and seeing . When you apply an impulse, the physics engine will apply forces and resolve collisions in such a way that the physicsBody's velocity is updated. When you set it yourself, you might find that it is ending up at a value that pushes it a little to far into the other sprite/ ends up resolving the velocity to 0,0

Comment: Still seems to happen when using an `applyImpulse`

Comment: hmm... what's your fps when it happens? If you can get a cut down sample I could probably help. Now I'm wondering how you are scrolling the background + blocks? Have you attached a camera to the main block?

Comment: It's normal FPS (~60 or so). I don't have any camera attached. I'm moving the blocks across the screen via an `SKAction`

Comment: Wow, thanks for tracking that down! I never would have found that

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: since you've clarified your question a bit and you seem to want the red one to fall back to the ground, while the blue blocks stay where they were, it seems that the bodies may be too rough, which makes them stick, and the red one doesn't slide off.

There's the `friction` property - modifying it can turn the body from a rough one (1.0) to one that's as smooth as an ice cube (0). Per the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKPhysicsBody_Ref/Reference/Reference.html#jumpTo_13), the default value is 0.2, which may still be too rough for your needs. Try setting it to `physicsBody.friction = 0.0` in all involved bodies.

EDIT 2: it seems that it's a deeper bug. You can try the following workarounds to achieve your desired effect, if you want to sacrifice a little accuracy:

- set your first blue block physics body to the target rectangle size, then make each subsequent lower block body 1-2 pixels narrower, so that you evade the 'lip'
- set your physics bodies to circles rather than rectangles if all else fails - `bodyWithCircleOfRadius:self.size.width*0.5`. For a fast enough simulation, this might do.

Comment: Actually I would like the 2 blue blocks to act as a wall (2 high by 1 deep). They're positioned directly on top of one another but for some reason I can still jump up onto the lower one and sit there which shouldn't be happening. They shouldn't move at all

Comment: ah, so you want the red one to bounce off them back to the ground?

Comment: Yeah, It seems like it's getting caught on a "lip" or something despite being precisely aligned.

Comment: also, you might want to file a radar -http://blackpixel.com/blog/2012/02/radar-or-gtfo.html

Answer (score 0):

I could imagine that tiny numerical errors in the simulation run by SpriteKit, in particular regarding collision detection and motion will make the red box indeed sit on the edge of the lower blue box. This position may be stable simply because the blue box accelerates the red box leftwards for the short amount of time it remains on screen.

A solution could be to use specific body types that merge the different configurations of boxes with smooth left vertical surfaces that occur in your game. In the specific case, it would be a box that is twice as high than wide. Before you spend a lot of time on this, you could test first of all, if removing the lower blue box stops the red box from getting stuck.

You don't need to define different `Block` classes for different box configurations: your `initWithColor:(UIColor *)color size:(CGSize)size` already appears to accept different sizes, but you might want to provide additional texture tiles and identifiers for those to select from.

Comment: Well I'm planning on building much more complex objects out of the individual blocks which is the reason I didn't want to use a single 2x1 block. This is just a simplified example to illustrate the bug

Comment: I see, it may be then that you're better off without the physics engine of SpriteKit. Have you considered running a much simpler simulation yourself? The kind of advanced collision detection that screws you may not be necessary in your world.